# get subquery and count as colomn

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I've a blog system with a simple version control system. My DB is:

```
|id------|parent_id|title------------------|
|1       |1        |Test title             |
|2       |1        |Test title 2           |
|3       |1        |Last test title        |
|4       |4        |Another blog item      |
```

My query to get only the lastest versions (only 3 and 4) is:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY id DESC) b
GROUP BY b.parent_id
```

Result:

- Last test title
- Another blog item

My question is: is it possible to count the number of all sub versions?, like:

- Last test title (3)
- Another blog item (1)

Answer (score 1):

You query is not guaranteed to work.  You can read about MySQL group by extensions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  Basically, the fields produced by the `*` are not guaranteed to come from the "first" record.  I want to stress that this is documented not to work, even though it might work in practice.

An alternative way to write your query is:

```
select b.*, p.numchildren
from (select parent_id, max(id) as maxid, count(*) as numchildren
      from blogs
      group by parent_id
     ) p join
     blogs b
     on b.id = p.maxid
order by b.parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!! this is what i wanted!